# Can you preprocess a specific region in template.php?

Tags: 7, theming

In your template.php file, I know you can use theme_preprocess_region and check what "region" you are in, and accomplish what I am attempting like that...but I was wondering if you can do something like theme_preprocess_region_specific_region to further break things up and not have a lengthy preprocess_region function?  I can't seem to find any documentation on that.

Comment: There are hook suggestions in https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes%21theme.inc/function/template_preprocess_region/7 ...maybe you can use `hook_preprocess_region__NAME`?

Comment: From [https://drupal.org/node/1089656](https://drupal.org/node/1089656) : 

`A theme hook suggestions is an alternate template (.tpl.php) file that you have created to override the base or original template file.`

So it could work, but it is not really the same than a preprocess function.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, you can define your own preprocess function if you want to, since you have all the elements for that. In the theme_preprocess_region function, you can simple do :

```
$function = 'yourtheme_preprocess_region_'.$variables['region'];
if (function_exists($function)) {
  $function($variables);
}
```

Then, you just have to define the a function for your region :

```
function yourtheme_preprocess_region_YOURREGION(&$variables) {

}
```